# PHP $_ENV vs Linux environment (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, linux

In my PHP code I am trying to access my linux system environment variable that I export in /etc/profile.

When I type "printenv" in my terminal, I can see that the variable (called MEMCACHED_1) set.

But my PHP doesn't see that variable, it's neither in $_ENV array nor can I access it with getenv function.

In my php.ini file I set `variables_order = "EGPCS"`. That added a lot of variables to $_ENV, but MEMCACHED_1 is still not there.

Comment: I'd post this on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) too and there may be crossover in terms of `$_ENV` and `/etc/profile` domain knowledge which would help.

Comment: Works in me 'buntu, what does `MEMCACHED_1=foobar php -r'var_dump($_ENV);' | grep  -A 1 MEM` on the command line yield?
`

Comment: Nothing. Without "| grep MEM" it returns this: array(0) {
}

Answer (score 0):

What `php.ini` exactly do you mean? There are `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (configuration used by scripts run by Apache module) and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` (configuration used by command line scripts). The latter has `variables_order = "GPCS"` as default setting on Ubuntu.

If you are running your code from command line, try changing `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and setting `variables_order = "EGPCS"`.

If you are using Apache module, you may want to access needed variables as `$_SERVER` instead of `$_ENV`, or call `getenv()` before as comments here suggest: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

**UPDATE**

Another thing to remember: PHP processes started by Apache module are run with user `www-data` (or whatever your `User` variable in Apache configuration says). So, you should also check `printenv` for correct user:

```
 sudo su -l www-data -c 'printenv'
```

-- this should have line `USER=www-data` or something similar (not root, not your login). Make sure `MEMCACHED_1` is set there.

Comment: I am running the app on Apache, and I set  (variables_order = "EGPCS" ) in my /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: `<?php var_dump($_ENV);` << what would this page display?

Comment: My PHP can't see MEMCACHED_1 linux environment variable in any of $_ENV, $_SERVER or getenv

Comment: hudolejev, whole bunch of stuff, but no MEMCACHED_1. Similar to the output of printenv, but not exactly the same. For example, the value of MAIL is /var/mail/root, but when I do printenv the value of MAIL is /var/mail/MY_USER_NAME

Comment: hudolejev, but when I run printenv as SU, looks like the env vars displayed are the same. I think you gave me a clue

Comment: See the 'UPDATE' section in my post, just added. You are probably setting the variable for a wrong user. Your variable should be set for the same user environment that is used to run the script (root, or www-data in your case -- not sure, but not your own user).

Comment: The variables output by var_dump($_ENV) are clearly root's variables. But apache is running under www-data user (who does have MEMCACHED_1 variable). How is that possible?